# CSS console auto calculated values?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a site from scratch and I decided to go on wix, however I don't understand this coded on css' console and this is my problem,

the width and left is auto calculated, i removed the width and this is the result:
[image]

There is this code in it,

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

I tried not to change it but only the inline elements are highlight, should I add width and left in it? what should I put is it auto? what should i put on the negative value? auto negative? help?

Comment: `position: absolute;` is going to skew it. It's css anarchy. Once you have it, everything else fades to background. use position relative and work with it. If you had some html up, that would help with an exact solution.

Comment: did you try removing that left:-235 ?

Comment: it is auto calculate, if i put that, it will not display properly, this is my https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/byq02L9t/, please inspect on headerWidthBackground, how can i make it through Whole width, i tried width 100% it's still in the center?

Comment: @NagaSaiA it has same effect on the width, on the screenshot I removed the width

Comment: jsfiddle is not working

Comment: @NagaSaiA here, https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/byq02L9t/1/  , i want it to cosume the whole width, what should i put on width and left? it is auto calculated and left is negative value?

Comment: width: 100% !important;

Comment: use this css which will mantain that width:100%

Comment: it's still in the center, not the whole width